# Gorilla mux returns blank url params during tests

Tags: google-app-engine, go

The code below extracts the url value when running the appengine server, but during tests the url var are blank.

Any ideas to why this would be?

```
func init() {
    s := scheduleApi{}
    r := NewAERouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/leagues/{leagueId}/schedule", s.get).Methods("GET")

    http.Handle("/", r.router)
}

func (s *scheduleApi) get(c appengine.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    params := mux.Vars(r)

    fmt.Printf("=======================\n")
    fmt.Printf("URL => %v\n", r.URL)
    fmt.Printf("params => %v\n", params)               // empty map
    fmt.Printf("leageid => %v\n", params["leagueId"])  // blank
    fmt.Printf("=======================\n")
}
```

Test

```
func Test_Get(t *testing.T) {
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/leagues/99/schedule", nil)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()

    handler := http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        s := scheduleApi{}
        c, _ := aetest.NewContext(nil)
        s.get(c, w, r)
    })
    handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)

            //...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gorilla mux needs to be included in your test. In your app code you are setting up the route using mux but in your test you are not.

Here is a [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/Xs-Ho1feGyg) dealing with this issue on go-nuts.